# SKScene doesn't deinit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I encountered a big problem to my application. My MainMenu scene doesn't deallocate when I transition to a new one.

```
//GameViewController

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = MainMenu(fileNamed: "MainMenu") {
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            view.presentScene(scene)
       }
}
```

[image]

I tap the button to enter a new SKScene which has the following code:

```
let transition = SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0)
let next_scene = LuckyScene(fileNamed: "LuckyScene")
next_scene?.scaleMode = scaleMode
view?.presentScene(next_scene!, transition: transition)
```

It openes my Lucky Scene but it doesn't call the deinit function from Main Menu.

Afterwards, if I do the same thing from the Lucky scene, for example I want to leave the scene and go back to Main Menu, the scene it's getting deallocated leaving me with a huge problem.

```
let transition = SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0)
let next_scene = MainMenu(fileNamed: "MainMenu")
next_scene?.scaleMode = scaleMode
view?.presentScene(next_scene!, transition: transition)
```

If the user enters Lucky Scene and leaves it, a new MainMenu Scene will be created.

[image]

Why my MainMenu scene is not getting deallocated when I transition to a new one?

Comment: you have a reference to your MainMenu somewhere ... find that property and make it `weak`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Answer (score 1):

After a long time, found the answer. The problem was that this SKAction was not removed.

```
let bear_animation : SKAction = SKAction.repeatForever( SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(idle_animation), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0), SKAction.run(wave_animation), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0)]))        
run(bear_animation, withKey: "bear_animation")

func idle_animation()
{
    left_arm.run(idle_left_arm)      
    right_arm.run(idle_right_arm)
    body.run(idle_body)
}

func wave_animation()
{
    right_arm.run(wave_right_arm_1)
    right_arm.run(wave_right_arm_2) 
    left_arm.run(wave_left_arm)
    body.run(wave_body)
    left_pupil.run(wave_pupil)
    right_pupil.run(wave_pupil)
    left_eyebrow.run(wave_eyebrow)
    right_eyebrow.run(wave_eyebrow)
}
```

So, when I was presenting a new scene, I added this like of code.

```
removeAction(forKey: "bear_animation")

let transition = SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0)
let next_scene = LuckyScene(fileNamed: "LuckyScene")
next_scene?.scaleMode = scaleMode
view?.presentScene(next_scene!, transition: transition)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the the animation action, but the  actions inside of it.

`SKAction.run(idle_animation)` is a strong reference to `self`, so your sprite is holding onto `idle_animation`, and `idle_animation` is holding on to sprite, which means your retain count will never go to 0.  I would avoid using functions and instead use weak self closures

```
var idle_animation =
{
    [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else return
    strongSelf.left_arm.run(strongSelf.idle_left_arm)      
    strongSelf.right_arm.run(strongSelf.idle_right_arm)
    strongSelf.body.run(strongSelf.idle_body)
}
```

This way the animation will drop once the sprite has been removed from the scene since there is no retain holding it back. (Note, you need to do this approach for your other animations as well)

Comment: I have some further questions, can I get your twitter?